# Time Complexity of the static Character.isLetter in Java

Tags: java, string, static, char, time-complexity

I am currently solving one of Leetcode's questions on strings. I need to check that all of my string literals are ***letters***.

I have the attached code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
     char character = s.charAt(i);
     if (!Character.isLetter(character))
        return s;
     lastIndex[character - 'a'] = i;
 }
```

What is the time complexity of checking that a string contains all letters?

I think it's O(n) though since the check will be done for all the characters in the string.

Thanks.

Comment: [In the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char)), no time complexity is given. So this answer would be implementation-specific. We can always take a look at the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/dc4322602480/src/share/classes/java/lang/Character.java#l5793).

Comment: It all depends on how the `charAt()` is being performed and if there's a backing array. You can get around that by usin `for (char c : s.toCharArray())`

Comment: I agree with you @Turing85. It's most likely constant.